# Are there stats on how many successful dribblings has Lionel Messi made with his national team?

Tags: football

According to several wikis, Q/A websites, etc. Lionel Messi holds the record of most successful dribblings in World Cup matches. Not sure where these stats comes from but apparently it was made by some british company of sports analysis. Also, competitions like Copa América played by his national team also release dribbling stats.

Are there stats on how many successful dribblings has Lionel Messi made with his national team including all official matches?

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely statistics on players' dribble success rate. Some companies like [Statsbomb](https://statsbomb.com/data/) provide detailed event data for a fee. On the other hand websites like [Fotmob](https://www.fotmob.com/) and [Transfermarkt](https://www.transfermarkt.com/) provide in-game statistics, but don't have comprehensive disaggregations of dribble success.

A quick web search of "Messi dribble success" took me to this article: ["Most successful dribblers in 2020-21 named, Leo Messi only 2nd"](https://tribuna.com/en/news/fcbarcelona-2021-05-15-most-successful-dribblers-in-202021-named-leo-messi-only-2nd). The first line references data was sourced from [WhoScored.com](https://www.whoscored.com/) (if you're a football/stats nerd, you ought to know about WhoScored).

Another web search of "WhoScored 2014 world cup" navigated me to this page: [World Cup 2014 Player Statistics](https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/247/Tournaments/36/Seasons/3768/Stages/10274/PlayerStatistics/International-FIFA-World-Cup-2014). In the first table, I selected "Dribbles" by "Totals" and searched. This rendered that Messi completed 46 out of his attempted 73 dribbles for the 2014 WC.

Now this approach only provides data for the 7 games that Messi played for Argentina for the 2014 WC. Navigating to the "History" tab of [Messi's player page](https://www.whoscored.com/Players/11119/History/Lionel-Messi) provides a year-competition-level look (once again selecting "Dribbles" and "Totals"). It appears that statistics are only available for official competitions like the World Cup and the Copa America (interesting note here, the number of successful dribbles in this view for 2014 WC is 39 instead of 46 as documented in the WC player statistics view). Rendering the following:

> 2014 WC 39 successful dribbles
>
> 2015 Copa 42
>
> 2018 WC 23
>
> 2019 Copa 22

I'm not sure how much data collection occurs for International friendlies or World Cup qualifies, but I imagine this is will be a little harder to find.